# Linq infinite nested query

Tags: c#, linq, nested

I need to get a node of a nested collection looking through It's deep with linq.

This is the nested class:

```
public class Group
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }

}
```

Each instance of this class can have multiple instances inside the Groups method and so on. Each instance is linked through the ParentId property.

I need, having an instance of Group class, retrieve his father. I tried with this:

```
var parent = _repositoryGroups
.Where(g => g.Id == [my Group instance].ParentId)
.SelectMany(g => g.Groups)
.FirstOrDefault()
```

I don't know why, but not always it find the father instance and It starts looking from the second level (but this is not a real problem).

What's the best way to find the element through all the deep of this nested class?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are misusing the SelectMany. If you delete the line it should work

Comment: I agree with @Schiavini. Without the `SelectMany` the query returns you the first group that has the wanted id (returns the father). Selecting all the groups from that parent and then taking the first looks like it will return the parent's first child, which isn't the parent, obviously.

Comment: It doesn't work without the `SelectMany`. It retrieve only the groups under the first level...

Comment: If I understood your question, you wanted only the parent right? If you want all the childs of the parent, remove the FirstOrDefault then

Comment: Group 1
 -> Group 2
  -> Group 3
  
Yes, I want just the parent. My repository has just one element inside (Group 1), I want to know the father of Group 3. I need to loop all the nested groups till the Id property is equals to the ParentId of my child element. Thanks.

Comment: So in this case group 1 is the parent of group 2, and you want to find group 2 because it's the parent of group 3??

Answer (score 2):

It now sounds like you want to get all childs recursively of a certain group.

So you can have:

```
private IEnumerable<Group> EnumerateChildren(Group parent)
{
    if (parent.Groups != null)
    {
        foreach (var g in parent.Groups)
        {
            yield return g;

            foreach (var sub in EnumerateChildren(g))
            {
                yield return sub;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want to get the parent of a certain group:

```
private Group GetParent(Group child)
{
    _repositoryGroups.Where(g => g.Id == child.ParentId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And if you need to get the super-parent of a certain group (parent of parent of parent of...):

```
private Group GetSuperParent(Group child)
{
    parent = GetParent(child);

    while (parent != null)
    {
        child = parent;
        parent = GetParent(child);
    }

    return child;
}
```

Above it all, I recommend that if you can do that, hold a reference to the parent instead of it's Id. Have it null if it has no father. Saves a lot of trouble. A lot.

Comment: it's `children`, not `childs` :-)

Comment: I fall for it myself all the time :-)

Comment: @BigYellowCactus Fixed it now :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go up your structure and find the last parent of the parents, you can use this piece of code:

```
var group = [my Group instance];

while(group.ParentId > 0)
{
    group = _repositoryGroups.First(g => g.Id == group.ParentId);
}
```

This assumes your IDs are higher than zero, and that an id>0 will always have a valid parent.

Comment: There is no gurantee that valid Id's are above zero, nor that the group necessarily has a father, which will cause `First` to throw an exception for not finding any.

Comment: Indeed, I just added my assumptions to the answer

Comment: I would consider going for FirstOrDefault, checking for null, and throwing custom exception of "RepositoryGroups corrupted - Parent not found" or something like that, if you're going for the assuming approach anyway.

Comment: That would be a valid approach indeed, however I think this code is much easier to understand, and an Exeption thrown by Linq would be sufficient. I believe it's a matter of taste.
Anyway, I totally agree with your comment on having references to the parent, instead of the ID. Id's are a misconception coming from the gap between object oriented programming and relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, maybe I didn't explain my question very well. I've developed this solution inspiring to yours answers:

```
private static Group GetGroupFather(IEnumerable<Group> groups, Group child)

{

    foreach (var group in groups)
{

    // try to nested search
    var result = GetGroupFather(group.Groups, child);

    if (result != null) return result;

    // check in the current level
    if (group.Id == child.ParentId)

        return group;

}

return null;

}
```

If you have a better solution using linq, please let me know.

Comment: The child object is not changing at all. Can't you use `_repositoryGroups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == child.ParentId)` ?

Comment: I use the child just to get the parent id. I can't use your code because it retrieve the groups just from the first level of  `_repositoryGroups` not from a nested situation, for example, `_repositoryGroups[0].Groups[2].Groups[1].Groups[2].id == child.ParentId`